# How to copy input's value with clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clipboard.js

I don't know how to copy the value to clipboard from the input without using ID!

Here is JS:

```
  new Clipboard(".form__copy-btn", {
    target: function (trigger) {
      return $(trigger).closest(".form__field-wrapper").find("input");
    }
  });
```

[Here is codepen](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/mMPjqq?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening here:

1. jQuery doesn't work withing the clipboard return function. I passed it using `var j = $;`
2. You are trying to return a jQuery element and clipboard.js only takes a native JS element. Instead of using `target:` use `text:` - that way you can pass the exact text string instead of the element.

This worked for me:

```
var j = $;

_document.ready(function () {

new Clipboard(".form__copy-btn", {
    text: function(trigger) {
        return j(trigger).closest(".form__field-wrapper").find("input").val();
    }
  });

...
```

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mirohristov/pen/GvZXpY)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your codepen. I have made below changes and copy is working

1. Remove clipboard js plugin code from js and add itin setting as external resource resource in js section (external resource cdn link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.7.1/clipboard.min.js)
2. I have made below change in your code

   ```
   /** I have used text method for copy and it is working **/
   var clipboard = new Clipboard(".form__copy-btn", {
   text: function(trigger) {
           // console.log($(trigger).closest(".form__field-wrapper").find("input").val());
     return $(trigger).closest(".form__field-wrapper").find("input").val();
   }
   });
   ```

Comment: but it doesn't work, Uncaught TypeError: trigger.parent is not a function

Comment: @SilencerWeb I have edited my answer. Can you please do said changes in answer and try?

Comment: @Kashyap are you kidding me? You just copied my answer and edited yours one hour after I answered it? Come on!

Comment: @Miro I am sorry for this but honestly, I had no clue that you had already given same solution. I was working on codepen and once I got solution I just posted it without checking other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.execCommand('copy')` to copy the value to clipboard from the input. See [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to check details and browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I found another answer, here it is:

```
  new Clipboard(".form__copy-btn", {
    target: function (trigger) {
      return $(trigger).closest(".form__field-wrapper").find("input").get(0);
    }
  });
```